# linq joinについて

Tags: c#, linq

凄く基本的な事なのですが、

```
var test = (from a in dataTable1
            join b in datatable2 on new {a.ID, a.date, a.No} equals {b.ID, b.date, b.No}
            select new {
                      a.ID,
                      a.date,
                      a.No,
                      b.coment,
                      b.sozai,
                      a.note
                      }).Distinct();
```

joinした時の結果なのですが、
これはa.ID, a.date, a.Noが共通のデータしか結果として出てこないのでしょうか？
もし、dataTable1とdatatable2 の共通のデータプラスお互いのテーブルにしかないデータも同時に抽出したい場合はどのようなlinqとなるのでしょうか？
また、 a.note,b.coment,b.sozaiに値が入っていなければ空白もしくはnullとして結果を表示したいです。
ご教授いただけると幸いです。

.net 3.5
windows 8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> これはa.ID, a.date, a.Noが共通のデータしか結果として出てこないのでしょうか？

`join`演算子を使うと内部結合になりますので結合できなかったエンティティの組は出力されません。

Entity Frameworkで完全外部結合を実現するには一度両テーブルを`UNION`してから左外部結合を二回行うか、グループ化により代替する必要があります。

下記のコードは前者の方法を使用しています。

```
var keys = datatable1.Select(_ => new { _.ID, _.date, _.No })
                .Union(datatable2.Select(_ => new { _.ID, _.date, _.No }))
                .Distinct();
var test = from k in keys
            join a in datatable1 on new { k.ID, k.date, k.No } equals new { a.ID, a.date, a.No } into a2
            from a in a2.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join b in datatable2 on new { k.ID, k.date, k.No } equals new { b.ID, b.date, b.No } into b2
            from b in b2.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new {
                k.ID,
                k.date,
                k.No,
                b.coment,
                b.sozai,
                a.note
            };

test.Distinct();
```

なお、

> また、 a.note,b.coment,b.sozaiに値が入っていなければ空白もしくはnullとして結果を表示したいです。

については外部結合を行った場合の結合されなかったエンティティのプロパティは既定値になります。ですので`string`を`null`としたいのであれば上のように特に工夫は必要ありません。`int`その他の値型は`0`となるので、この動作が不都合である場合は

```
select new {
    …
    SomeProperty = (int?)a.SomeProperty,
    OtherProperty = a != null ? a.OtherProperty : -1,
    LastProperty = a.StringNotNullProperty != null ? a.LastProperty : -1,
    …
}
```

のようにキャストや三項演算を追加してやれば回避できます。

Comment: @pgrhoさん、いつも回答ありがとうございます。早速、試させていただいているのですが、nullの回避がどうしてもうまく行きません。三項演算子だと、型intの値が型int?のnullに等しくなることはないので、式の結果は常にtureになります。問事です。キャストをしても、nullリファレンスで止まってしまいます。この場合のnullの回避はどうすればよいのでしょうか？

Comment: @BAKZ .NET Framework 3.5ということですので、キャストが出来ないのはライブラリ(Entity FramewokまたはLINQ to SQL)でサポートされていないからでしょうね。となるとNOT NULLな文字列型があればそれが`null`かどうか判定するのが良いと思います。

Comment: @pgrhoさん、文字列の三項演算子はうまく行っていると思うのですが、int型の部分で止まってしまいます。note = a.note != null ? a.note : 0とすると”型intの値‌​が型int?のnullに等しくなることは‌​ないので、式の結果は常にtrueになりま‌​す。”になります。しかし、実際には最初にunionしているのでdatatable1をjoinしている時にnoteのプロパティがnulになります。その場合の回避はどうすればよいでしょうか？

Comment: @BAKZ 条件を`a`もしくはその他の非`null`列の判定としてください。

Comment: select newの時の条件という事でしょうか？

Comment: あまりうまく行かなかったので他の方法を試してみました。ですが、うまく行かない状況です...。